# Change default remote git branch in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

For some reason, my local `dev` branch is my default release branch. Is there any way in the IntelliJ UI to change this?

[image]

For clarification, by "default" I mean the default for that branch, not for all branches. The default for all branches is supposed the branch name itself. I do not know how my `dev`'s default got changed.

Comment: That question is over 11 years old, and doesn't seem to relate to my question about changing the default remote branch of a current local branch.

Comment: I think you want to change upstream and it is only possible via command line https://phoenixnap.com/kb/git-set-upstream

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No GUI way to do it in IntelliJ 2021.2.3, though it's been a feature request for 3 years. If interested, [add your vote to IDEA-197078 at IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197078).

To set a new upstream, use the IntelliJ terminal and type:
`git branch -u <remote>/<branch>`.

If running Git for Windows:
`git branch --set-upstream-to <remote>/<branch>`.

More info about branches [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) from the official online reference guide [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) (a great resource!).